# Error "error: load the kernel first" in PrimeOS. How to fix this error?

Tags: kernel, failed-installation, linux-distro

As from the title, you would know that this is pretty common. There are numerous forums about this.
But no one has a perfect solution.

When I boot into prime OS (installed using .exe), it always gives the error "load kernel first".
I don't know hot to fix this.

Also, I don't know how can I enable CSM on modern systems.
or if it is related to Secure boot in any way.

When I use .iso on my flash drive, the Install menu loads, I hit enter on "PrimeOS 2.1.3 Installation" and nothing. Complete black.

Some times I get the error that "ROOT VARIABLE MUST BE SET!".

Originally the error also consisted of the problem that initrd.img and Kernel files weren't found (no such device error). But when I edited the path from `/initrd.img` to `/mnt/initrd.img`, and the same for kernel through the commandline (c) , it didn't encounter those errors again. But the root variable not set and kernel must be loaded errors persist. Please help.